# How to thousand separate sum of column in Asp.NET cshtml

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, razor

While trying to print the sum of the columns in the datatable, I want to print the data that comes as a result of the sum as thousands separator.

Im trying to separate this

`<td class="number">#SUM|toFixed(0)|toLocaleString(tr-TR)#</td>`

It gives me : 100000

I want this : 100.000

Comment: did you try toFixed(2) ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tostring?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 0):

You need to use N0 format. N will format it with thousand seperator, and 0 will delete decimal:

```
string.Format("{0:N0}", 100000);
```

and make sure set your cultureinfo in global.asax or program for your region

```
var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("tr-TR");
cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd-MM-yyyy";
cultureInfo.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";
cultureInfo.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
cultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencyGroupSeparator = ".";
cultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ",";

Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
```

or based asp or mvc

```
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
```

in your .cshtml it should look like this

```
<td class="number">@string.Format("{0:N0}", sum)</td>
```